# Como hacer la función ''si esto no esta activado, muestra un texto''

Tags: php

Hola tengo una variable que me muestra el nombre del usuario que esta registrado, el problema es que cuando no hay ninguno, me sale un

> notice de undefined index,

Tiene toda la razón. Entonces me gustaria hacer es, que cuando esto pase, de que no hay usuario en el **log in**, me muestre un texto de usuario no registrado por ejemplo en cambio de el **notice con undefined index**. Gracias.

```
 <p>Welcome: <?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?></p>
```

He probado con if pero no me ha salido bien.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usa el operador de **fusión null** representado por `??` para comprobar si la variable esta definida y tiene valor asignado,  en caso contrario asignarle un valor por *default* así:

```
 <p>Welcome: <?php echo $_SESSION['name'] ?? "Usuario no registrado"; ?></p>
```

Ahora si trabajas en una versión inferior a la 7 de PHP y por ende no cuentas con dicha característica, pudieras manejarlo de este modo:

```
$name = $_SESSION['name'];

if(!empty($name) && isset($name)) {
    echo "Bienvenido: {$name}";
}else{
    echo "Usuario no registrado";
}
```

**Explicación**

- Usamos `empty` negándolo para validar que la variable no este vacía
- Usamos `isset` para determinar que la variable esté definida

**Referencias**

- [Operador de fusión `null`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration70.new-features.php)
- [función isset](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php)
- [función empty](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php)

Comment: Gracias, me funciono la primera opción, no probé la segunda ya que la primera ya funcionó, gracias